# Make GNU parallel return the server name in the sshlogin file

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I run commands on several remote servers using gnu parallel with the help of a sshlogin file:

```
seq 3 | parallel --sshloginfile hostfile "/etc/sin/bin/daemon status"
```

The output looks something like:

```
hostfile: RUNNING, pid 1234567
```

And the file hostfile contains a list of servers like below?

```
server1.finehost.prod
server2.finehost.prod
server3.finehost.prod
```

My question is:

Is there any way to show the hostnames so that the output looks like that:

```
server1.finehost.prod: RUNNING, pid 12345
server2.finehost.prod: RUNNING, pid 666
server3.finehost.prod: STOPPED
```

Thanks ;)

---

Note: *I don't have permissions to install any extra tool on the servers such as pssh or similars.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you use the `seq 3` for. If that is not needed then this will work:

```
parallel --sshloginfile hostfile --tag --nonall "/etc/sin/bin/daemon status"
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks, this really does the job!
I thought that parallel needed to work through a pipe like xargs. The manual is somewhat confusing.
I am actually recurring to parallel as an alternative to pssh which is not installed in these servers.

Comment: `--nonall` is a bit special that way: it does not take any arguments. Consider spending an hour walking through the tutorial `man parallel_tutorial`. Your command line will love you for it.